# Changes saving in many entities takes a lot of time (Breeze SaveChanges method)

Tags: breeze

I use Breeze with Entity Framework Code First Model.

The usual operations with a database (MySQL) works fine, but when I save one parent entity with 50-60 child entities (relation one-to-many), operation saving takes a lot of time - near 40 sec. - 1 min. The entities don't have many properties and MySQL installed on local computer.

How can I speed up this operation?

Comment: Does this happen on each save or only on the first one?

Comment: This happen on each save. I have noted that saving simple child entities (without additional relations, only usual properties) goes quickly. But if I want to save child entities with some 1-to-1 relations - operation saving takes 40-60 sec.

Comment: I will give this a look first thing in the morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to repro this and have so far been unable to.  My test saves 5 parent entities (Customers) each with 49 child entities (Orders) in just under 1 second ( so 250 entities total). I am using the NorthwindIB SQL Server database that we include in the breeze DocCode sample. (in the breeze sample zip available on the download page).

Can you test your save without breeze being involved to see if maybe the issue has to do with the MySQL EF provider that you are using? I'm just guessing here.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. The source of this problem was in client side, not database. There is a string in breeze.js updateEntity function: `targetEntity.setProperty(dp.name, val);`. If val == undefined, then this function works for a long time (~500 ms in Chrome and AMD X2 processor). I don't know why, may be some knockout conversions. In my case in each of 50 entities was ~ 1-7 such undefined properties. As a result the operation saving takes ~40 sec. I have added the next condition before setProperty function to speedup this: `if (val === undefined) val = null;`.Now operation takes 5-10 s.

Comment: Hm, do you think the slowdown is breeze or knockout?